# Get next element after the active

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get the next dt after the dt with class active?

my HTML::

```
<dt class="active">...</dt>
<dd>...</dd>

<dt>...</dt>
<dd>...</dd>

<dt>...</dt>
<dd>...</dd>
```

look, i have this function:

```
    function slideShow() {
    var active  = $('dl dt.active',ctx);
    active.next('dt').addClass('active');
};
window.setInterval(slideShow, 5000);
```

should be simple. every  sec the DOM show where the active dt is and set the next dt of this active.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is

```
$('.active').nextUntil('dt').last().next()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g6yg6/)

For the slide show

```
var $dts = $('dl dt');
function slideShow() {
    var index = $dts.index($dts.filter('.active').removeClass('active')) + 1;
    var active = $dts.eq(index > 0 && index < $dts.length ? index : 0);
    active.addClass('active');
};
window.setInterval(slideShow, 1000);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XvvDP/)

Comment: @KevinBowersox `.next()` will fetch the next sibling of the element in this case the next sibling is the `dd` element not the desired `dt` element

Comment: But what if you provide a tag selector to next `next("dt")`

Comment: @KevinBowersox still it doesn't work because jQuery tries to apply the selector on the next sibling and will select the element only if it satisfies the selector... so it is an extra condition on the next sibling

Comment: @KevinBowersox see `Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks I thought it would just keep going through the siblings until a match is found.

Comment: @KevinBowersox no it won't

Comment: @ArunPJohny `$('.active').nextAll('dt').first()` is a better solution.

Comment: @ArunPJohny all next `dt` siblings.

Answer (score 2):

Its not so simple, you can use the next sibling selector `~` in combination with `eq()` to select the element:

```
$(".active ~dt:eq(0)")
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/hsAA7/

Comment: This do not works because: `jQuery` cant identify the `dt` using as `next()` parameter, look, if you try only `.next()` you will find the next element. So you have alternative using `.nextAll('dt')` to see all next `dt` elements and `.nextAll('dt').first()` to get the first next `dt` element.

Comment: @PauloRoberto Thanks for the heads up.  I got to learn something new :)